# opencv class "cvKalman" not recognised

Tags: opencv, ros, kalman-filter

I have a problem, in ROS I process a camera feed with openCv. 
Now i try to implement the cvKalman, but this type is not recognized, however the opencv example works well.

What am i missing, why is not recognized this type?

here is my include to the ROS node:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

// for img processing 
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


#include <opencv/cv.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solves the problem by using the `KalmanFilter` wrapper class, but still I dont understand why I cant use the simple `Kalman` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try including with `"`s not `<`s such as:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
```

Comment: what is the difference? I thought that `<` is used for standard libraries and `"` used for own libs.